Shinyapp.io gives quartoinspect() when trying to publish Shiny App
Trying to publish my Shiny App through shinyapp.io. The app works fine locally. When trying to run deploy it I get the following error:

I don't have a Quarto document, nor do I know what they are. Below are the only files in my working directory:

I've tried searching why this issue comes up, but can't find ANYTHING relating to quartoinspect() and deploying the shiny app into shinyapp.io. I've updated my RStudio and made sure rsconnect is updated as well. I also installed the quarto package just to see if that would do anything, but no luc

I found renaming my app script to app.R solved this.  Any other name results in plenty of errors as shown above: not a valid quarto document.

I was getting this Exact same error.
I renamed my R Script to app.R.
I then put this R Script into a directory with nothing else inside of it. I also noticed that "rsconnect" was not loaded in properly; there was no checkmark next to the box in the Packages tab.
I ran library(rsconnect) to load the package in.
I then set the working directory to the directory where the app.R script was located.
setwd("path/to/your/R Script/")
Finally I ran "rsconnect::deployApp()" in the console. Everything worked fine after that.
Disclaimer: I am not a Shiny expert, I just started yesterday. But I was getting your error and was able to fix it. Hope this helps!
